# Equation solver in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpq

I want to write a program in `SWI-Prolog` that solves equations. I know `GNU Prolog` and that makes me nervous... What is wrong here?

```
equation(X1,X2) :-
  {
    2*X1 + 3*X2 =:= 6,
    {X1 is 0; X1 is 1},
    {X2 is 0; X2 is 1}
  }.
```

`X1` and `X2` always equal to `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a file with

```
:- [library(clpq)].
eq(X1, X2) :- {2 * X1 + 3 * X2 =:= 6}.
```

then I compile and run and I get:

```
?- eq(A,B).
{B=2-2 rdiv 3*A}.
```

It's the result you're expecting?

*edit*

```
?- eq(A,B),A=1.
A = 1,
B = 4 rdiv 3.

?- eq(A,B),B=1.
A = 3 rdiv 2,
B = 1.
```

Section A.8.3  of the [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.8%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpqr.html%27%29%29) says that unification can hold 'outside' constraints specification. Then you can experiment freely with additional bounding. But if you impose that both A and B will bind, you should choose appropriate values. AFAIK the values you posted initially cannot satisfy the equation.

Comment: I want X1 and X2 to be 0 or 1, so I need to specify a domain for them, but I don't know how. In GNU Prolog I'd do it like this: `fd_domain(X1, {0,1})`. In SWI Prolog I can't make it work (I need this prolog, because the factors could be decimal.