# prolog how to use math operation

Tags: prolog, clpfd, integer-arithmetic

I am a novice in prolog programming, i use swi-prolog. Now I'm stucked by some math problems

as we know the predicate :`A is 3+3.`works well,the answer is `A=6`.

but if I want to find two digits (A and B) from 0~9 that a+b=6 
`6 is A+B` does't work. so I want to know if there is a easy way to do this? And what if I want to find 3 digits (A,B and C)from 0~9 that A+B+C=13 how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simpler way, working in every Prolog implementation: declare a predicate digit/1 (the notation predicate/N means that predicate has N arguments)

```
digit(D) :- member(D, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).
```

then you can ask

```
?- digit(A),digit(B),6 is A+B.
A = 0,
B = 6 ;
A = 1,
B = 5 ;
...
```

since sum is symmetric, maybe you want to reduce the duplicate solution with

```
?- digit(A),digit(B),A=<B,6 is A+B.
```

Using library(clpfd) you can avoid defining your digit/1 predicate, and gain a lot of functionality:

```
?- [library(clpfd)].
true.

?- [A,B,C] ins 0..9, A+B+C #= 13, label([A,B,C]).
A = 0,
B = 4,
C = 9 ;
A = 0,
B = 5,
C = 8 
...
```

note that now the incognite can stay to the left of the 'assignment'...

Answer (score 2):

My advice to you as a Prolog novice is this:

1. First things first!
2. **Use clpfd!** You can start *right now* by reading the tag information section on tag [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd).
3. Pick up the habit of starting new file with extension `.pl` with the following line:

   ```
   :- use_module(library(clpfd)).
   ```
4. Use clpfd **everytime** you want to express Prolog relations over integers: *Every. Single. Time.*
5. **Witness** that clpfd is already widely available *and* that it is *still gaining ground*.
6. **Realize** that you will profit the most if you **learn [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) first**—not 1970's style `(is)/2`!

   Why? `(is)/2` is a *low-level feature* best used by constraint solver implementors.

Answer (score 1):

Doing math with prolog is interesting.
This looks like an assignment and I would not like to solve it, but I will try to help you find the answer yourself.
Given the restricted range of your problem you could probably define every integer from 0 to 9 by creating a simple prolog programm.
Keep in mind that you can define also functions like:

> add3(A, B, C,SUM) :- SUM is A + B + C.

You could try to solve the problem by an Equation Solver.
See this answer:
[Equation solver in SWI-Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857045/equation-solver-in-swi-prolog)

Or using Constraint Logic Programming.
http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpqr.html